# How do I read a 2D array as it is from a .txt file?

Tags: java, stream, io, jtable, multidimensional-array

I have this .txt file with the following format and contents (take note of the spaces):

```
Apples   00:00:34
Jessica  00:01:34
Cassadee 00:00:20
```

I want to store them into a 2D array (`holder[5][2]`) AND at the same time output them into a `JTable`. I already know how to write and read files in java and putting the read file into the array. However, when I use this code:

```
   try {

        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fi);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            for(int i = 0; i < holder.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < holder[i].length; j++){
                    holder[i][j] = line;
                }  
            }
        }

        in.close();


        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My `holder[][]` array isn't outputting very well as a JTable :| Help please? Thanks to whoever can help me!

Edit: Also is it possible to do this with a `Scanner`? I understand Scanners much better.

Comment: You don't need `DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fi);`. Use the `FileInputStream` directly into the `InputStreamReader` which is passed to `BufferedReader`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you will need is something like this:

```
int lineCount = 0;
int wordCount = 0;
String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            String[] word = line.split("\\s+");
            for(String segment : word)
            {
                holder[lineCount][wordCount++] = segment;                    
            }
            lineCount++;
            wordCount = 0; //I think now it should work, before I forgot to reset the count.
        }
```

Please note that this code is untested, but it should give you the general idea.

Edit: The `\\s+` is a regular expression which is used to denote one or more white space characters, be it a space or a tab. Technically, the regex is simply `\s+` but we need to add an extra space since the `\` is an escape character Java, so you need to escape it, thus the extra `\`. The plus is simply the operator which denote on or more of.

Second Edit: Yes you can do this also with `Scanner` like so:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(...));
while ((line = input.next()) != null) {...}
```

Comment: What does this mean? "\\s+"? Sorry, I'm pretty new to Java.

Comment: @taeyeon: I have modified my response. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Kevin: I think you mean: It matches strings which consist of at least one white space character, not the other way round ;)

Comment: @npinti This is really helpful. However, I got an ArrayOutOfBounds Exception in this line: `holder[lineCount][wordCount++] = segment;` I think wordCount exceeded holder's length.

Comment: @taeyeon: Like I said, the code is not tested. The issue most likely is that the array locations needs to be swapped, ie. use `holder[wordCount++][lineCount] = segment`. The code should work.

Comment: Nope, still didn't work, but I'll work on that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @taeyeon: I think I missed something, check my post again please.

Comment: Flawless. Thanks so much for solving my problem!